# Can I nest clicks for ajax calls within previously appended call results?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, nested

I'm making some early attempts at educating myself in AJAX and trying to speed pages rather than relying on PHP to show results.  I have hit a hurdle.

I essentially have 3 tiers of data. With 3 database tables.

- The **first tier of data** is pulled via a **PHP** loop and displayed upon page load.
- The **second tier of data** is loaded via **AJAX** when A is clicked and then appended to the page via jQuery.
- The **third tier** (where I'm having trouble) is loaded via **AJAX** when the second tier is clicked...and appended *within* the previously appended B data.

Like so....

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->
<!-- PHP loop to pull list if Item A data upon page load -->

<p><a href="#" id="A-id" data="NUM" class="a-call">Item A</a></p>
        <!-- click Item A -> AJAX pull B data and append results to .a-results -->

     <div class="a-results">

        <p><a href="#" id="B-id" data="NUM" class="b-call">Item B</a></p>

        <!-- click Item B -> AJAX and append results to .b-results -->

             <div class="b-results">
                <p>B resultrow</p>
                <p>B resultrow</p>
                <p>B resultrow</p>
                <p>B resultrow</p>
             </div>
     </div>
```

Ajax examples:

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
$('a.a-call').click( function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        var sid = $(this).attr('data');
        $.ajax({                                      
              url: 'secondtier.php',  
              type: 'POST',
              dataType: 'json',  
              data: ({sid: sid}),      
              success: function(rows) {
                    for (var i in rows) {
                        var row = rows[i];
                        var id = row[0]; 
                        var name = row[1];  
                        var type = row[2]; 

                        $('.a-result').append("<p><a href='#' id='s"+id+"' data='"+id+"' class='b-call'>id: " + id + " name: " + name + " type: " + type + "</a></p><div class='b-data'></div>"); 
                    }
                }
              });
      });

$('a.b-call').click( function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        var bid = $(this).attr('data');
        $.ajax({                                      
              url: 'thirdtier.php',  
              type: 'POST',
              dataType: 'json',  
              data: ({bid: bid}),      
              success: function(rows) {
                    for (var i in rows) {
                        var row = rows[i];
                        var id = row[0]; 
                        var data = row[1];  
                        var cost = row[2]; 

                        $(this).next('.b-data').append("<p>date: " + date + " cost: " + cost + "</p>"); 
                    }
                }
              });
      });
```

My AJAX calls work in themselves, however I can't get the **B** call to append results within the A results. The Item B AJAX works just fine if it's hard coded into the HTML, it's only when it's appended that I can't get it work. **No console errors anywhere.** Just nothing happening on the page.

I'm not totally current on jQuery usage. I tried `.live('click', function()` for the Item B click, however the console is telling me it's not valid. I assumed jQuery dropped that at some point.

Using google to link to jquery 1.9.1

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->
<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Am I going about this wrong? Can I get the appended anchor in **B** to call another ajax function and append more to the previously appended div?

I don't want to load all this data at once. This is my very reason for learning AJAX. The page currently loads everything via PHP and due to the amount of datasets within datasets it's a slow page load. I'm trying to get specific data to only load upon a click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `delegate()` , because `.b-call` elements does not exist on page load, so jQuery doesnt know where those elements are. So you need to delegate an event to an element that will exist after page load.

```
$('.a-result').delegate('.b-call','click',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        var bid = $(this).attr('data');
        $.ajax({                                      
              url: 'thirdtier.php',  
              type: 'POST',
              dataType: 'json',  
              data: ({bid: bid}),      
              success: function(rows) {
                    for (var i in rows) {
                        var row = rows[i];
                        var id = row[0]; 
                        var data = row[1];  
                        var cost = row[2]; 

                        $(this).next('.b-data').append("<p>date: " + date + " cost: " + cost + "</p>"); 
                    }
                }
              });
      });
```

Comment: Thank you. Using either `on` or `delegate` work. Is there a specific benefit to choosing `delegate`?

Comment: Nothing really. Just syntax . You can use on since its shorter. on applies to bind, live, delegate

`$(selector).delegate(subselector, events, data, handler);
$(selector).on(events, subselector, data, handler);`

Comment: Note that I ran into the issue with other items (using jeditables on span click events) and `.on()` did not work, but `.delegate()` does, so it was worth using this method for additional appended items.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is due to the fact that the link for fetching the `B` data is created when `A` is fetched.

The click event handler (`$('a.b-call').click`) is registered before the actual DOM element exists and therefore it does not get triggered.

To get this event handler working you need to change your code. The `a-results` div exists on page load, so you can attach the event handler to this element and simply specify the selector for `a.b-call`:

Example:

```
$('.a-results').on('click', 'a.b-call', function(e) {
    // your B load code here
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Using either `on` or `delegate` work. Is there a specific benefit to choosing `on`?

Comment: Basically you could use both approaches, but as of jQuery Version 1.7 the `on` delegates are the prefered approach.